# Cant get PHP to accept the POUND sign from a beautiful soup Python script

Tags: php, python, utf-8, beautifulsoup, utf

SO I have a script that pulls information from an event webpage. URL is this: http://everguide.com.au/melbourne/event/2012-jul-14/colour/

This php script is calling a python script (its part of a for loop):

```
${"tmp" . $i} = utf8_encode (exec("python myscrape.py ${"eu" . $i}"));
```

It passes a URL.  The python script is this:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys
URL = sys.argv[1]
#$URL = 'http://everguide.com.au/melbourne/event/2012-jul-14/colour/'

import urllib2
req = urllib2.Request(URL)
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
html = response.read()

from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.decode('utf-8'))
soup.prettify()

import re


for node in soup.findAll(itemprop="name"):
    n = ''.join(node.findAll(text=True)) 
for node in soup.findAll(itemprop="url"):
    v = ''.join(node.findAll(text=True))

for node in soup.findAll("div", { "class" : "time" }):
    d = ''.join(node.findAll(text=True))

for node in soup.findAll("a", { "id" : "ctl00_holderBody_ctl00_lnkCat" }):
    c = ''.join(node.findAll(text=True)) 

vu = v
vu.encode('utf-8', 'xmlcharrefreplace')
re.escape(vu)

print n,"|", d,"|", vu,"|", c
```

Which works really well, but only returns up to the or pipe before VU - it cant go past that!

The UTF-8 encoding is set on all files, HTML and php.

When there is a special character in the V variable, it breaks and stops.  If there are no special characters, it works perfectly.

Expected output is:

```
Colour | 14 July @ 7:30PM | 1000 £ Bend | Clubs & Parties
```

This ouutput can be seen when running the script on the server (with same python command) but over PHP - i cant get the Venue string back in!

Please help

Rick

Comment: Did you try adding htmlspecialchars to the variables?

Comment: Thanks Danis - in addition to Maria's answer that fixed the problem. Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`vu.encode` returns encoded string ... as you're not assigning the encoded result, this is just getting thrown away. Have you tried

`vu = vu.encode('utf-8', 'xmlcharrefreplace')`

You'll also need to skip the escape as it will mess up encoded unicode.

Comment: Thanks Maria.  With Dainis's remark about making sure htmlspecialchars() was set in place all over the shop as soon as the data was received back into the PHP - you are correct, that works perfectly!  I doubt this problem would have happened if the Beautifulsoup documentation provided real examples of usage, rather than plain theory!  Thanks!